# Get value of input type radio and redirect depending which one is selected

Tags: php, html, css, ajax, laravel

I have this view:

```
<h2>¿Este cliente esta relacionado con un proyecto existente?</h2>
<form  enctype="multipart/form-data" id="redirectProject" name="redirectProject">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="optRadio">Si</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="optRadio">No</label>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Avanzar" id="redirectProjectsubmit" class="btn btn-danger btn-md">
        <br><br><br>
    </div>
</form>
```

And I want to redirect the user when they click the input depending on which input is selected.

I want to use it with ajax.

How should the controller function and the route look?

I think ajax can help do it.

Thanks a lot, any help will be appreciated, if have any question about code or the question please ask it.

Comment: You mean redirect to different controller methods based on radio selection?

Comment: What have you tried? Please share your approachs

Comment: I think this must be what i have to do. If user select 'si' / 'yes' i will hide the code i attached on question (is on a div) and i will display an other div with one form. (i do this with ajax). And if user put 'no'/'not' i like to make a redirect to other url.

Comment: Use jquery to get the value of the radio, like this $("input[name='optRadio']:checked").val();  and for URL navigation in  ajax do .success and ,error based on your requirements.

Comment: Hi @ggderas now i'm trying to make a controller who takes the value of input. But now have idea of the url, i guess i have to pass a parameter. I think option of Hema Nandagopal it's more easy. I will try it.

Answer (score 3):

you can do it using jquery onclick function. add a class or id to both your radio button as below.

```
  <h2>¿Este cliente esta relacionado con un proyecto existente?</h2>

          <form  enctype="multipart/form-data" id="redirectProject" name="redirectProject">
                <div class="form-group">

                  <div class="radio">
                  <label><input type="radio" class="si" name="optRadio">Si</label>
                  </div>

                  <div class="radio">
                  <label><input type="radio" class="no" name="optRadio">No</label>
                  </div>
                  <input type="submit" value="Avanzar" id="redirectProjectsubmit" class="btn btn-danger btn-md">
                  <br><br><br>

                </div>
          </form>
    <script>

   //when you click yes
    $('.si').click(function(event){
        window.location.replace("http://redirect_to_your_location.com");
    });

   //when you click no
   $('.no').click(function(event){
        window.location.replace("http://redirect_to_your_location.com");
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi @steveokay first of all, thanks for your answer. Your code works and looks easy to understand. I like to do it when i click on submit, and then redirect. But i think, it's more easy like you do it. Let me ask you something, i have this code: `$('.no').click(function(event){
        window.location.replace("http://web.loc/admin/projects");
        $("#listallprojects").hide();
        $("#formcrearproyecto").fadeIn(1000);
    });` the problem now, it's all was after the window location replace, doesn't work. Know why?

Comment: Its is because you are redirecting first then hiding and fading. you should apply the other two properties first before redirecting e.g.  $('.no').click(function(event){ $("#listallprojects").hide(); $("#formcrearproyecto").fadeIn(1000); window.location.href("http://web.loc/admin/projects"); });

Comment: It's not that, i try it too :(

Answer (score 1):

This is just a basic idea, you can adjust it for your needs easily :)

Add values to your form radio.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="redirectProject" name="redirectProject">
        <div class="form-group">

          <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="optRadio" value="1">Si</label>
          </div>

          <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="optRadio" value="0">No</label>
          </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Avanzar" id="redirectProjectsubmit" class="btn btn-danger btn-md">
          <br><br><br>

        </div>
  </form>
```

Your controller should look something like this.

```
SomeController extends Controller {

    public function inputRedirect(Request $request) {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            if ($request->input('optRadio') {
                return redirect('/somwhere');
            } else {
                return redirect('/somwhere-else');
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

And add your routes like this in your `route.php` file for laravel <= 5.3, or `routes/web.php` for laravel >= 5.4

```
Route::get('/somewhere');
Route::get('/somwhere-else');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @blackcat i will try it. Let me ask you something, the route which will go when i click to the submit how looks like? i think i have to pass the value on the url, true? If you can edit your own answer, i will appreciate it a lot!.

Answer (score 0):

Two things,

1. You need to give value to your radio buttons

   ```
   <div class="radio">
       <label><input type="radio" name="optRadio" value="yes">Si</label>
   </div>
   <div class="radio">
       <label><input type="radio" name="optRadio" value="no">No</label>
   </div>
   ```
2. Attach an event listener on the click of radio and redirect accordingly

   ```
   $("[name=optRadio]").on("click", function () {
       var selected_value = $(this).val();
       if (selected_value == 'yes') {
           // Hide the div
       } else {
           window.location.href = "{{ url('path where to redirect') }}";
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: Hi @linktoahref i try your code and isn't working. html code looks like yours, ajax looks like here `$("[name=optRadio]").on("click", function () {
        var selected_value = $(this).val();
        if (selected_val == 'yes') {
            $("#clienteproject").hide();
        } else {
            window.location.href = "{{ url('path where to redirect') }}";
        }
    });` and if I click yes, he redirect to: `http://web.loc/admin/clients?optRadio=yes`

Comment: @LluísPuigFerrer sorry there was a typo in the if condition, answer updated

Comment: I try it again and isn't working. If i click on radio button si, don't do nothing. if i click on submit goes to: `http://web.loc/admin/clients?optRadio=yes`

Comment: Excuse me mate.. was my fault. I change the id of the div. Thanks a lot ;)!

Comment: let me ask you something, in else i want to go to: http://web.loc/admin/projects and hide a div with id listallprojects how to do it?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to hide `#listallprojects` if  you are going to redirect, won't that render a new page anyway

Comment: mmm, the page i redirect, return other view, and that view contain the div :l

Comment: So you need to set a variable, say in session in the controller and check in the view for `session('your key')` If it is set don't display the `div` else show the div

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150837/discussion-between-lluis-puig-ferrer-and-linktoahref).

Answer (score 0):

Assign a click listener on each radio and when it is triggered, use jQuery to query the form that surrounds them - now you should have access to the `optRadio` value.

After that, check for true or false values of optRadio i.e

( this is sudo code but the idea is there ;-) )

```js
let radio = //value from form

if(radio) {
  //redirect user after selecting 'Si'
} else {
  //redirect user after selecting 'No'
}

or

window.location = radio ? *Si url* : *No url*
```